# How to get text from textfield in php?

Tags: php

I have simple php script that contains this part:

```
$user = '<input type="text" name="name1" id="username" value="'.$firsttext.'">';
echo $user;
```

Do someone know how to get the text from the field? Thanks

I tried

```
echo $_GET['username'];
```

I am noob in php

Comment: $_GET['username'] will only contain the value of the input element with the name="username" (not id="username") when you submit the data thru the GET method

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="GET">
      <input type="text" name="name1" id="username" value="<?php echo $firsttext; ?>">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

**To retrieve the value using $_GET:**

```
$firsttext = $_GET['name1']; 
echo $firsttext;
```

Make sure that the name attribute of the input field and the key used in $_GET match. In this case, you should use **$_GET['name1']** to access the value of the "**name1**" input field.